# What is the difference between a java method reference expression and a variable defined as a lambda?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I was trying to create a static List of conditions (`Patterns`) related to actions (`Consumers`) for a project of mine.

I originally created the atomic actions like this :

```java
public abstract class Number implements MorphoSyntacticFeature {
  public static void singular(Set<MorphoSyntacticFeature> s) {
    s.add(SINGULAR);
  }
  public static void plural(Set<MorphoSyntacticFeature> s) {
    s.add(PLURAL);
  }
}

public abstract class Person implements MorphoSyntacticFeature {
  public static void first(Set<MorphoSyntacticFeature> s) {
    s.add(FIRST);
  }
  public static void second(Set<MorphoSyntacticFeature> s) {
    s.add(SECOND);
  }
}
```

where `FIRST`, `SECOND`, `SINGULAR`, `PLURAL`, ... are instances of anonymous subclasses of `Number` and `Person`.

I created the static list like this :

```java
private static Map<Pattern, Consumer<Set<MorphoSyntacticFeature>>> actions = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  static {
    actions.put(Pattern.compile("^(?:je|j’)"), Person::first);
    actions.put(Pattern.compile("^tu"), Person::second);
  }
```

But indeed, I'd like 2 atomic actions to be performed for these patterns and thought it would be easy to compose both actions using `andThen`.

I thought I would be able to use :

```java
    actions.put(Pattern.compile("^(?:je|j’)"), Person::first.andThen(Number::singular);
```

But this leads to a syntax error.

I finally changed the definition of the actions :

```java
public abstract class Number implements MorphoSyntacticFeature {
  public static Consumer<Set<MorphoSyntacticFeature>> singular = s -> s.add(SINGULAR);

}
public abstract class Person implements MorphoSyntacticFeature {
  public static Consumer<Set<MorphoSyntacticFeature>> first = s -> s.add(FIRST);
  ...
}
```

With this definition, I managed to create the list with :

```java
    actions.put(Pattern.compile("^(?:je|j’)"), Person.first.andThen(Number.singular));
```

For the sake of completeness, the static list is used like this :

```java
 private void handleGrammaticalContext(LexicalForm f, Element leftContext) {
    String c = standardizeValue(leftContext.text().trim()).replaceAll("^(?:que |qu’)", "");
    actions.forEach((pattern, action) -> {
      if (pattern.matcher(c).find())
        action.accept(f.getFeature());
    });
  }
```

My question is, why do I have to create static fields (`Consumer`) in the `Number` and `Person` classes and what is the difference between `Person.singular` (as a `Consumer` instance) and `Person::singular` (when singular is defined as a `static` method) ?

Comment: It sounds like the substance of your question is _why can't I invoke interface methods on a method handle usable as a functional interface_; is that correct?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Well, I'm not really sure about the vocabulary, maybe more *what is the difference between a method reference expression and a variable defined as a lambda?* 
It could be *why can't I invoke interface methods on a method reference usable as a functional interface?* but I'm not sure of the wording and I'd like an answer that may explain other related symptoms.

Comment: Would be nice to see the syntax error you get in the first version.

Comment: For giggles, what happens if you say `((Consumer<Set<MorphoSyntacticFeature>>) Person::first).andThen`?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek with `actions.put(Pattern.compile("^(?:je|j’)"), Person::first.andThen(Number::singular);` the error is : `Main.java:[11,52] method reference not expected here` so this is syntactically illicit.

@chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- with `((Consumer<Set<MorphoSyntacticFeature>>) Person::first).andThen(Number::plural));`it compiles correctly. 
Don't know how to interpret this... Person::first is not a Consumer without a typecasting.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. It doesn’t matter whether the variable has been initialized with a lambda expression or a method reference. All that matters, is that a variable has a declared type. Without a declared type, you can’t invoke a method.